# Как можно сделать, возврат разного типа переменной 'int, float' из функции на си?

Tags: c

Есть у меня функция 'popStack' которая должна возвращать в зависимости от типа float или int.

```
float popStack(void);
int popStack(void);
```

int - 4 байта;
float - 4 байта;

Comment: Никак. Перегрузка возможна только в С++, и то не по возвращаемому типу. Вот кусок кода: `...; popStack(); ...;` - какая из функций должна быть вызвана? вот и компилятор не поймет...

Comment: Псевдо перегрузку можно в си сделать конечно, но только в си11 и только по передаваемым параметрам. Вот [пример](https://learnc.info/c/generic.html) вдруг пригодиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если смотреть стандарт языка С, то там написано (Working Draft, 1997-11-21, WG14/N794 J11/97-158) в разделе 6.7.1 :

> 3 The return type of a function shall be void or an object type other
> than array type.

Т.е. можно возвращать любой тип, кроме массива. Но, на самом деле, толку от этого не много, т.к. можно возвращать значение любого, но **одного** типа.

Ну вот такой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    float x;
    int n;
} flint;

flint z;

flint popStack(void) {
    return z;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int j;
float r;
flint fl;

    z.x = 25.5;
    fl = popStack();
    printf("%6.2f\n", fl.x);

    z.n = 25;
    fl = popStack();
    printf("%6d\n", fl.n);

}
```

Вывод этой программы будет таким:

```
$ ./a.out 
 25.50
    25
```

Вроде бы - да, возвращается и целое значение и плавающее... Только пользоваться этим всё равно - не удобно!

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вроде псевдо перегрузки, но все равно нужно передавать параметр [c11](/questions/tagged/c11):

```
#include <stdio.h>

float popStack_f(void) {
    return 1.0f;
}

int popStack_i(void) {
    return 6;
}

#define popStack(X) _Generic((X),   \
    int: popStack_i,                \
    float: popStack_f)()


int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", popStack((int)0));
    printf("%f\n", popStack((float)0));
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/kdMyhE

```
6
1.000000
```

Comment: Хотя бы ссылку на источник добавили, рас уж ответ по комментарию делаете. Хотя может я ошибаюсь конечно :))), но почему бы не добавить ссылочку

Comment: Ссылка? Ничего не понял, но вот: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic

Answer (score 0):

Возвращаемое значение должно быть одного типа. Но если хочется, то можно сделать виртуальный класс чисел.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 virtualplus.c -o virtualplus
enum  {
  virtualNumberInt  = 0 ,
  virtualNumberFloat  = 1 
} ;

typedef
struct  virtualNumber {
  int type  ;
  union {
    int i ;
    float f ;
  } ;
} virtualNumber ;

# include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf jbexception  ;

virtualNumber plus  (virtualNumber  x,virtualNumber  y){
  switch(x.type){
  case  virtualNumberInt  :
    switch(y.type){
      case  virtualNumberInt  :
        return  (virtualNumber){
          .type  = virtualNumberInt ,
          .i  = x.i + y.i } ;
      case  virtualNumberFloat :
        return  (virtualNumber){
          .type  = virtualNumberFloat ,
          .f  = x.i + y.f } ;
      default :
        longjmp(jbexception,1); }
  case  virtualNumberFloat  :
    switch(y.type){
      case  virtualNumberInt  :
        return  (virtualNumber){
          .type  = virtualNumberInt ,
          .f  = x.f + y.i } ;
      case  virtualNumberFloat :
        return  (virtualNumber){
          .type  = virtualNumberFloat ,
          .f  = x.f + y.f } ;
      default :
        longjmp(jbexception,1); }
  default :
    longjmp(jbexception,1); }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  if(setjmp(jbexception)) {
    fputs("exception: wrong number type",stderr);
    exit(1); }
  virtualNumber x = {.type = virtualNumberInt , .i = 1};
  virtualNumber y = {.type = virtualNumberFloat , .f = 1.0};
  virtualNumber z = plus(x,y);
  switch(z.type){
  case  virtualNumberInt  :
    printf("z(int)=%d\n",z.i);
    break;
  case  virtualNumberFloat  :
    printf("z(float)=%f\n",z.f);
    break;
  default :
    longjmp(jbexception,1); }
  }
```

проверка :

```
$ ./virtualplus 
z(float)=2.000000
```